# Typescript intellisense cannot infer generic type of conditional types based on condition

Tags: typescript

I've setup an interface that accepts a generic that extends a union. On that generic, I created a set of conditional types.

```js
type SessionContentType = "a" | "b" | "c";

interface SessionDetails<T extends SessionContentType> {
    id: string;
    sectionId?: string;
    segments?: string[];
    content: {
        type: T;
        contentId?: T extends Exclude<SessionContentType, 'b'> ? string : never;
        channelId?: T extends Exclude<SessionContentType, 'a'> ? string : never;
        suffix?: T extends Exclude<SessionContentType, 'a' | 'c'> ? string : never;
    }
}
```

Up to here, it seems everything fine. `SessionDetails["content"]["suffix"]` has the following type:

[image]

So, generic must be of type `'b'` for suffix to not be `never`.

Then I create a function that uses a structure that complies to `SessionDetails` with a known `T`.

```js
function getSuffixFromSession(
    session: SessionDetails<Exclude<SessionContentType, 'a'>>
) {
    if (session.content.type === 'c') {
        session.content.type; // This is correctly of type 'c'
        session.content.suffix; // I expect this to be of type 'never' but it is `string | undefined`

        return '';
    }

    const suffix = session.content.suffix ?? '';
    return suffix && `-${suffix}`;
}
```

Just to confirm I was doing everything correctly, I added those two detailed statements to see their types.

`session.content.type` is, as expected, of type `'c'`.
But if `type` is of type `c` (and therefore this should be writable as `SessionDetails<'c'>`), why does `session.content.suffix` resolves as type `string | undefined` instead of `never` (or `never | undefined`, actually?)?

If I do

```js
function getSuffixFromSession(
    session: SessionDetails<'c'>
) {
    if (session.content.type === 'c') {
        session.content.type; // This is correctly of type 'c'
        session.content.suffix; // I expect this to be of type 'never' but it is `undefined`

        return '';
    }

    const suffix = session.content.suffix ?? '';
    return suffix && `-${suffix}`;
}
```

`session.content.suffix` is `undefined` instead of `never`, but still this is not what I'd like to obtain.

Is there something wrong that am I doing or that probably I'm assuming?

[Here's the playground url.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhDO8CWB7AdgYXcCbgBVxoBeKAIgEMyoAfcgI2rrIGMyBuAKE6TwgCcAZhRbQ4iVGgAiEYBSQAbeAB58UCAA8caACbxYCZOix88hSAD4oAb04BIJDoBcUeMH68A5lzvwILYEkASR0Afhc3DzRvez9PAFtcYHhw13cvAG0AXR8WbCSXWzs7UEgXfB87PNNgENS1TW09KABRDRYFAFcdCGVxI0x8syIAGigAcnpxq1C0qM8oFzQIADcBSpYACwo0ZYU68vUtXGa2ju7e-skTbQJRiYppqFnIr0WoZbX+SvhOwUEkBp6kcmvozl0en1DNchndIGNxo9aBMWE8Xulou9Put7ABfTj4ziCTpoAKSKCeWQwP4AjQAMX4KHiV3QAApYtD0C4WdJZPIlMpwRcoRJjLDzBAEY8LBZOABKGz2JCCKCsvyitAAOmqt01pRIxFI41RCqKvk5Wp1ST1RB+Fu1sM1v3+gK49js-FknX4aAm4x8hKq6DcrhpgKgpHVAwdNSdYY0z1m4399k9wG9vudtKgADIc1AAAYAWgAJNYs4DcQWuISgA)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things are going on here.

---

One is that your `SessionDetails<T>` type does not actually constrain things the way you think it does.  When `T` is a union like `"b" | "c"`, the type of `SessionDetails<T>["content"]` is a single object type and not a union:

```
type Content = SessionDetails<Exclude<SessionContentType, 'a'>>["content"];
/* type Content = {
  type: "b" | "c";
  contentId?: string;
  channelId?: string;
  suffix?: string;
} */
```

Which means this is acceptable to the compiler:

```
const sd: SessionDetails<"b" | "c"> = {
    id: "",
    content: {
        type: "c",
        suffix: "oopsie" // <-- definitely a string
    }
}; // no error
getSuffixFromSession(sd);
```

Since your [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) for `content.suffix` evaluates to `string` when `T` is `"b" | "c"`, then even if you verify that `session.content.type` is `"c"` inside the implementation of `getSuffixFromSession()`, the type of `suffix` does not depend on it, and [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) does nothing.

---

The issue having to do with `undefined` versus `never` is that when you read an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) that happens to be missing, you will get a value of `undefined`:

```
interface Foo { bar?: never };
const foo: Foo = {}
console.log(foo.bar) // undefined
```

[The `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) represents an impossible condition; there are no values of type `never`, and if you get to a place in your code where the compiler thinks a value is of type `never`, then either the compiler is mistaken, or that place will never be reached at runtime.

When you have an optional property declared to be of type `never`, you are essentially saying that you expect the property not to exist at all.  There are some nuances around assigning `undefined` to such a property; it's currently allowed with `--strictNullChecks` but TS4.4 will introduce [an `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler flag](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#exact-optional-property-types) that will prevent it.  But either way, when you *read* an optional property of type `never`, you are definitely going to get an `undefined`.

So, receiving `undefined` is desired behavior.

---

Anyway, the only way to get this kind of "check one property of an object to narrow the type of the whole object" functionality in TypeScript is to use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  If you want your `content` property to be a union and not a single object type, you need to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) that property type across any union in `T`.  A distributive conditional type will do this automatically:

```
interface SessionDetails<T extends SessionContentType> {
    id: string;
    sectionId?: string;
    segments?: string[];
    content: T extends any ? { // <-- distributes
        type: T;
        contentId?: T extends Exclude<SessionContentType, 'b'> ? string : never;
        channelId?: T extends Exclude<SessionContentType, 'a'> ? string : never;
        suffix?: T extends Exclude<SessionContentType, 'a' | 'c'> ? string : never;
    } : never
}
```

Which you can verify:

```
type Content = SessionDetails<Exclude<SessionContentType, 'a'>>["content"];
/* type Content = {
  type: "b";
  contentId?: undefined;
  channelId?: string | undefined;
  suffix?: string | undefined;
} | {
  type: "c";
  contentId?: string | undefined;
  channelId?: string | undefined;
  suffix?: undefined;
} */
```

And thus the following assignment fails:

```
const sd: SessionDetails<"b" | "c"> = {
    id: "",
    content: { // error!
  //~~~~~~~ <--  Types of property 'suffix' are incompatible.
        type: "c",
        suffix: "oopsie"
    }
}
```

And control flow analysis inside the implementation of `getSuffixFromSession()` proceeds as desired:

```
function getSuffixFromSession(
    session: SessionDetails<Exclude<SessionContentType, 'a'>>
) {
    if (session.content.type === 'c') {
        session.content.type;
        session.content.suffix; // undefined
        return '';
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4Ch8BIAFwE8ZkBlaKDAe2AGFGSJgSAVC5AXiQBEIAUgA+ggEYjxA+AIDchIhg4Q0AMwTVaDYABEIJEBgA2UADyckEAB5tgAEyhIaUOoxaqO3SgD48xMoOAFxIUCSYwFiKRERQEPAkugCSDgD8oeGR0YHxWJAcUBlhESpYANoAujFE8KzsJKEEsaQ8oZw1tfUcqcVWtvZOSACiNvAmAK4OEOau7szdXDwANEgA5BJr-mkl2UihwBAAbmqd8AAWIMCHJr3t1nbsQ6PjUzNzup72S5SrayBbJA7LJlfZIQ4nNCdKATdTqDA2PoPQbOF6TaazHQeRY+CB-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-QDINGBDMMPpjOME2TPtU3TMCkYgn6BXmf7fmLcVy3y6tazHObhyZDtO27SsStCw8GjDiBR1j0O73kJBeqN+mlFiK8bxXNds6ku89xDodi9PfPLwXJcecjR9n3fL8fz-GGVK3KAQMR7lsximC5Hg-LkNQ9DFiadOzLUWM0AAQlnUyAD9F8XvqBu1XFnHoasYFjSg0HIdY7zWJAhOQFQ6jAOAkgkDSGymyhcLkfC+w+oiSLIijYmU5SaLoyN7aY0KLE2K2SAA)

Comment: What is this!! I'm very impressed by your such detailed reply and by what is going on and what to do. I actually expected the error to come from `suffix`'s type, not from the whole `content` object. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You're almost correct, you just want to swap `string` for `T`.

Like this:

```
type SessionContentType = "a" | "b" | "c";

interface SessionDetails<T extends SessionContentType> {
    id: string;
    sectionId?: string;
    segments?: string[];
    content: {
        type: T;
        contentId?: T extends Exclude<SessionContentType, 'b'> ? T : never;
        channelId?: T extends Exclude<SessionContentType, 'a'> ? T : never;
        suffix?: T extends Exclude<SessionContentType, 'a' | 'c'> ? T : never;
    }
}


function getSuffixFromSession(
    session: SessionDetails<Exclude<SessionContentType, 'a'>>
) {
    if (session.content.type === 'c') {
        session.content.type; // => 'c'
        session.content.suffix; // => 'b'

        return '';
    }

    const suffix = session.content.suffix ?? '';
    return suffix && `-${suffix}`;
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhDO8CWB7AdgYXcCbgBVxoBeKAIgEMyoAfcgI2rrIGMyBuAKE6TwgCcAZhRbQ4iVGgAiEYBSQAbeAB58UCAA8caACbxYCZOix88hSAD4oAb05R7UJDoBcUeMH68A5lwduILMCSAJI6APyu7p5oPnYO8BBeALa4wPARbh7eANoAur4OLNiprrZ+fqCQrvgF5VBFpsChGWqa2npQAKIaLAoArjoQyuJGmMVmRAA0UADk9DNWYVBqrmgQAG4CteUsABYUaGsKzdXqWrgd3b0DQyOSJtoEU7MUC1BLK1Brm-zbfvB9QSCJAaFpndr6K79QbDQz3cZPSDTGavWizFhvD5QVYbLZxewAX04RO4gj6aECkigXlkMEBwI0ADF+Cgknd0AAKfH+CToVzs6SyeRKZRQm6w3ljRrmCDI14WCycACUNm5SEEUA5CUlADoGo8dZUSMRSDMMSqynUeaM9QjDUR2FAAPROqDEKxmmbc-5w9C2xo6gFAkGOl1uj3zbhWqD8WR9fhoWYzbYkvwNdxuekgt3WyT+g1BhnvJYzZPc2PAeOJwvZgBktagAAMALQAEmsNY0BMbXCJQA)

Comment: This actually doesn't solve the issue: `suffix` must exist and be of type an arbitrary string (not one of SessionContentType) or not exist at all based on the conditions above, not of type 'b'.

Comment: @AlexanderCerutti `T extends Exclude<SessionContentType, 'a' | 'c'>` will only be true IF the value is `'b'`. If that's not what you want then please update your question to reflect exactly what you what/expect.

Comment: @jcalz's reply already explained everything. Anyway, the main reason for using such conditional is the will to omit the property the condition is assigned or keep it. But I don't want the final type of `suffix` to be `T`, because `T` is actually the type of prop `type`. The condition is done on the type of `type`. So, I wanted to achieve that if create a compliant object with `T='a'`, the compiler won't let me add `content.suffix` ('cause `never`) but if it is `'b'`, I wanted it to be present and allowing me to pass optionally an arbitrary string. Hope this is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

Since never would not display directly, you can replace the `never` with `number`, and you can see the following [image: type-interface]

I haven't dived into the TypeScript compiler source code, but I'm guessing that typescript is inferring `T` as `'b' | 'c'` here, so the `session` is inferred to `SessionDetails<'b' | 'c'>`, eventually the `session.content.suffix` will be inferred to `string | never | undefined`

If you really want impl like this, maybe this is a better way, explicitly tell the TypeScript `session` is a  `SessionDetail<'c'>`

```
(session as SessionDetails<'c'>).content.suffix; // (property) suffix?: never | undefined
```

Comment: This actually doesn't the issue: what I want actually to achieve is that if I create an object of type `SessionContentType<'a'>`, compiler must not allow me to add `suffix` because of wrong "requirement" of `'b'`.